# Hack Assembler in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

This is an assembler for the Hack assembly language as described in "The Elements of Computing Systems" by Nisan and Schocken, MIT Press. The details of the Hack computer and its assembly language can be found at http://www.nand2tetris.org/ if anybody is interested.

I am aware that I am not doing any sort of error checking at the moment. The program assumes all input is correct. I know using globals is generally frowned upon. I sort of feel like this example warrants the use but I am open to alternative approaches.

I am a novice when it comes to programming and this is my first assembler. I considered using something like PLY but felt this example language was so simple that it did not warrant it.

The program works in two stages. The first stage converts symbols that are defined in parenthesis such as (END) into program memory addresses and stores them in a symbol table. The second stage converts the assembly mnemonics into binary as well as tracks variable usage and memory addresses.

```
time ./hackasm.py Pong.asm > pong.hack
./hackasm.py Pong.asm > pong.hack  0.17s user 0.01s system 96% cpu 0.190 total

wc -l Pong.asm
   28375 Pong.asm
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    

import sys
import re    

destination = {'M': '001', 'D': '010', 'MD': '011', 'A': '100', 'AM': '101',
               'AD': '110', 'AMD': '111'}    

computation = {'0': '101010', '1': '111111', '-1': '111010', 'D': '001100',
               'A': '110000', '!D': '001101', '!A': '110001', '-D': '001111',
               '-A': '110011', 'D+1': '011111', 'A+1': '110111',
               'D-1': '001110', 'A-1': '110010', 'D+A': '000010',
               'D-A': '010011', 'A-D': '000111', 'D&A': '000000',
               'D|A': '010101', 'M': '110000', '!M': '110001', '-M': '110011',
               'M+1': '110111', 'M-1': '110010', 'D+M': '000010',
               'D-M': '010011', 'M-D': '000111', 'D&M': '000000',
               'D|M': '010101'}    

jumps = {'JGT': '001', 'JEQ': '010', 'JGE': '011', 'JLT': '100', 'JNE': '101',
         'JLE': '110', 'JMP': '111'}    

set_a_bit = set(["M", "!M", "-M", "M+1", "M-1", "D+M", "D-M", "M-D", "D&M", "D|M"])    

builtin_symbols = {'R0': 0, 'R1': 1, 'R2': 2, 'R3': 3, 'R4': 4, 'R5': 5,
                   'R6': 6, 'R7': 7, 'R8': 8, 'R9': 9, 'R10': 10, 'R11': 11,
                   'R12': 12, 'R13': 13, 'R14': 14, 'R15': 15, 'SP': 0,
                   'LCL': 1, 'ARG': 2, 'THIS': 3, 'THAT': 4, 'SCREEN': 16384,
                   'KBD': 24576}    

symbol_table = {}
user_def_vars = {}    

next_program_address = 0
next_memory_address = 16    


def stage1_symbol_table_generator(line):
    """
    Process a single line of Hack assembly. If the line contains a symbol
    check if it is in the global symbol_table. If not add it and return.
    If line is not a symbol incriment next_program_address and return.
    """
    global symbol_table
    global next_program_address
    token = re.split('(\(|\)|=|;|@)', line)
    if token[1] == '(':
        if token[2].isdigit():
            return
        if token[2] not in symbol_table:
            symbol_table[token[2]] = next_program_address
        return
    next_program_address += 1    


def stage2_code_generator(line):
    """
    Process a single line of Hack assembly. If the line contains a symbol
    look it up in the global symbol_table. Generate Hack machine code from
    Hack assembly code.
    """
    global next_memory_address
    global user_def_vars
    token = re.split('(\(|\)|=|;|@)', line)
    if token[1] == '(':
        return
    if token[1] == '=':
        a = '1' if token[2] in set_a_bit else '0'
        print('111' + a + computation[token[2]] + destination[token[0]] + '000')
        return
    if token[1] == ';':
        print('111' + '0' + computation[token[0]] + '000' + jumps[token[2]])
        return
    if token[1] == '@':
        if token[2].isdigit():
            print('0' + format(int(token[2]), '015b'))
            return
        if token[2] in symbol_table:
            print('0' + format(symbol_table[token[2]], '015b'))
            return
        if token[2] in builtin_symbols:
            print('0' + format(builtin_symbols[token[2]], '015b'))
            return
        if token[2] in user_def_vars:
            print('0' + format(user_def_vars[token[2]], '015b'))
            return
        user_def_vars[token[2]] = next_memory_address
        print('0' + format(next_memory_address, '015b'))
        next_memory_address += 1
        return
    else:
        return    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in open(sys.argv[1], 'r'):
        if line.strip():
            if not line.startswith("//"):
                stage1_symbol_table_generator(line.strip())
    for line in open(sys.argv[1], 'r'):
        if line.strip():
            if not line.startswith("//"):
                stage2_code_generator(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

While it might not be recommended by every programmer, I think OOP would clean your code up a lot here (at least reorganise it in a better way).

I have three main points of feedback:
 1. Globals (although at least you're aware of it)
 2. Hardcoding (magic numbers defined in amongst the code)
 3. Redundancy (some logic can be factored out for cleaner code)

Consider the following snippet:

```
# constants defined here to avoid magic numbers
COMMENT_PREFIX = "//"
DEFAULT_START_PROG_ADDR = 0
DEFAULT_START_MEM_ADDR = 16

class HackAssembler(object):
    # declare our instance variables here
    # now we can access them inside our class methods
    _symbol_table = {}
    _user_def_vars = {}

    _next_program_address = DEFAULT_START_PROG_ADDR
    _next_memory_address = DEFAULT_START_MEM_ADDR

    _lines = []

    def __init__(self, asm_file):
        # add each line in asm_file to our internal list
        for line in open(asm_file, 'r'):
            # we can stirp them here to avoid the extra conditional
            self._lines.append(line.strip())

    def assemble(self):
        # iterate over each line
        for line in self._lines:
            if not line.startswith(COMMENT_PREFIX):
                generate_symbol_table(line)
                generate_code(line)

    def generate_symbol_table(self, line):
        # ...

    def generate_code(self, line):
        # ...
```

Then, at the end of our file (outside the class declaration):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    assembler = HackAssembler(sys.argv[1])
    assembler.assemble() # run our code
```

Of course, (as always) your mileage may vary.

Regardless, for a beginner programmer, writing an assembler is impressive - keep building and making it better!